# New water pump and radiator and supposedly my head gaskets blew

Tags: ford, head-gasket, explorer

My water pump and radiator went out I took it in to a mechanic. They checked it all than replaced the parts,soon after getting it back it over heated and I took it back again,they said it was my head gaskets. Is it their fault? Plus, after being told this they tried to buy my vehicle, it felt like something was off in there tone and demeanor. It's a 2001 sports Trac explorer.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! That is the thing about intuition ... if it feels wrong, it probably is wrong. You most likely did a good thing. I'd suggest taking it to a different mechanic and having them take a look. I'm wondering if the original shop didn't get the cooling system purged of air completely. If they didn't, it could easily have caused the overheat issue. On the other hand, there is a reason these vehicles are nicknamed "Exploders". The engines on them were not really that good.